# $form_id: What is the difference between #id and #value?

Tags: forms

I am trying to find the $form_id using the Devel module.

Sometimes when I output a form, $form_id is output with a single value.  However, sometimes the output of `dpm($form)` looks like this:

[image: form_id output]

What is the difference between #value and #id here?  Which is the $form_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$form_id` always has `_` in it. Because in [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) you always have to put replace FORM_ID with $form_id so you can't put `-` in function name.

```
$form_id: String representing the name of the form itself. Typically this is the name of the function that generated the form.
```

And `#id` is html safe id. id attribute for form tag.